# Problem with showing correct delivery date

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website which shows the delivery date when you search product

P.S as an example, I use today's order which was created `30.08.2021 14:12`

Delivery date on the search result page show this code:

```
       if(time_to_exe == 7)
    {
var orderDateTime = moment();
// Get Monday (first day) of this week and add 3 days (to get to Thursday) and set the time to 11:59am
var cutOffDate = moment().startOf('week').add(3,'days').set({'hour': 11, 'minute': 59, 'second': 59});
// Initialize delivery date from order date
var deliveryDate = orderDateTime.clone();
if (orderDateTime.isSameOrBefore(cutOffDate)) {
    deliveryDate = deliveryDate.add(1,'week').startOf('week'); // Monday next week
} else {
    deliveryDate = deliveryDate.add(2,'week').startOf('week'); // Monday the week after next
}
    
    if (deliveryDate) {
  time_to_exe = deliveryDate.format("D. MMMM");
      
    } else {
      time_to_exe = time_to_exe + "d";
    }
    }
```

As the order was created in the time between `Monday 30.08.2021 00:00` and `Thursday 02.09.2021 11:59:59` the delivery date is `06.09.2021` which is correct

Then I have an Order page where clients can see all created orders and there is a delivery date as well. And there, the delivery date shows this code:

`$item_time` is defined as an order created date (in this case `30.08.2021 14:12`)

```
if($item_t2_time_to_exe == 7)
{
    
    $paymentDate = strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",$item_time);
//echo $paymentDate; // echos today! 
$contractDateBegin = strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",strtotime('monday this week', $item_time));
$contractDateEnd = strftime("%d/%m/%y 11:59:59", strtotime('thursday this week', $item_time));
    
if (($paymentDate >= $contractDateBegin) && ($paymentDate <= $contractDateEnd)){
     $nextMonday = strftime("%e.%B", strtotime('next monday',$item_time));
}else{
    $nextMonday = strftime("%e.%B", strtotime('second monday',$item_time));  
}
   if($nextMonday) 
   {
       $delivery = $nextMonday;
   }
   else
   {
       
       $delivery = "error";
   }
    
}
```

And there it should be the same delivery date `06.09.2021` as it is on the search result page, but for now, the code executes `else` and return me `'second monday'` and show `13.09.2021` as a delivery date. I can't understand why it is so, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem

Found on google that `strftime` can't compare

So I changed this

```
    $paymentDate = strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",$item_time);
//echo $paymentDate; // echos today! 
$contractDateBegin = strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",strtotime('monday this week', $item_time));
$contractDateEnd = strftime("%d/%m/%y 11:59:59", strtotime('thursday this week', $item_time));
```

to this

```
    $paymentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$item_time);
//echo $paymentDate; // echos today! 
$contractDateBegin = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('monday this week', $item_time));
$contractDateEnd = date('Y-m-d 11:59:59', strtotime('thursday this week', $item_time));
```

For now, it looks like everything works fine

Comment: _"Found on google that `strftime` can't compare"_ - that's not really the issue, the problem is that the date format you used was not "sortable". Since this is string comparison, the date parts need to come in the proper order, from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
$contractDateEnd = strftime("%d/%m/%y 11:59:59", strtotime('thursday this week', $item_time));
```

Maybe you'll need (with 23:59:59):

```
$contractDateEnd = strftime("%d/%m/%y 23:59:59", strtotime('thursday this week', $item_time));
```

14:12 ist bigger than 11:59, so the second monday could be right.

Comment: 11:59:59 this time was meant as 11:59 AM, you need to make order before 12 PM to get delivery on next Monday after 12 PM should be second monday